# sed: jump to next input file

Tags: sed

Is there an option or command similar to `grep`'s `-m1` or `awk`'s `nextfile` for `sed`, which would allow `sed` to immediately stop processing the current input file when a match is found (while continuing to process subsequent input files)?

For example:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -ns '/pattern/{<do stuff>; p; <next>}' {} +
```

where `<next>` would be a command to cease reading the current input file.  The quit command (`q`) is not suitable, since it simply causes `sed` to exit (abandoning subsequent input files), and would therefore find at most one match per batch of input files.

Comment: how about using `\;` instead of `+` so that `sed` sees only one file input at a time?

Comment: @Sundeep: I had thought about that, but I prefer to use `+` for performance reasons.

Comment: in that case perhaps use `awk` or `perl` as they do have ability to skip rest of the lines... if your input is ASCII, using `LC_ALL=C` will give you speed boost.. perhaps use `xargs` to parallelize.. and do at least try `\;` with `q`.. it isn't always easy to know speed results without actually performing the tests

Comment: @Sundeep: Thanks, `LC_ALL=C` is a good point in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Example wit search and replace:

**GNU sed**

stops processing file/input (thanks to `sed`'s `-s` option and `find`'s `+`) after first occurrence of pattern.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -ns '0,/pattern/s/patter/replacement/p' "{}" +
```

**BSD sed**

BSD `sed` seems to lack `-s` option. So I'm using [Sundeep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/109046/sundeep)'s suggestion.

Quit `sed` after first occurrence of pattern and `find` will execute `sed` with next file.

```
find . -type f -exec sed -n '0,/pattern/p;s/pattern/replacement/p;q' "{}" \;
```

Comment: Thanks.  The address range (`0,/pattern/`) does work, though it requires searching for the pattern twice (in the general case, `<do stuff>` might not involve a substitution on the pattern).

Comment: It should work with different things than substitution as well.

Comment: To see that it does not generalize, compare the output of `seq 10 | sed -n '0,/9/ s/9/A/p'` and `seq 10 | sed -n '0,/9/ ='`.  Also, the address range only restricts execution of those commands, but processing will continue until `EOF`, which may be undesirable for large input files.

Comment: There's one more option how to possibly speed it up. You can `find . -type f -print 0 | xargs -0 -P XX -L YY sed …` this will run max XX parallel seds each with up to YY arguments from find. But it's possible that your `<do stuff>` isn't a good case for this.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point as well.  In this case, unmixed output is preferred, so `parallel` could be used.

Comment: Feel free to expand the answer with the solution that solved your question

Comment: Well, I gather that the answer to the question is that it's not possible (i.e., there is no option or command that allows GNU `sed to jump to the next input file).